# Safety types and definition

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, machine-design

I am searching for some Engineering terms but couldn't find any of the definition.

1. Direct safety
2. Indirect safety
3. Warnings

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

These terms are difficult to define: depending on the application, functions, types, moments, quantity, quality, etc. For this reason, when speaking of these terms a series of conditionals are specified that end up being regulated by some institution (For example: ISO, ANSI, EC, CE, etc.) Then, you can find, for example, "safety" in machine building. However, after a revision I can't find the terms "Direct/Indirect safety" on books. Might you please tell us where do you read/hear about that?

Comment: Thank you for clearing it. What i want to ask os on terms of machine elements design or generally Engineering design.